# SQL Query using MAX() function in where condition and display data

Tags: sql, select, max

I have a DataTable in which I have `LCNo (string)`, `AmmendmentNo (string)`. I want to retrieve the row which has highest `AmmendmentNo` for a respective `LCNo`

For example:

> LCNO (123,123,123,123)
>   AmmendmentNo (0,1,2,3)

I want the row which has LCNo: 123 and AmmendmentNo: 3

```
select * from LCTable where LCNo= '12147001' AND MAX(AmendmentNo);
```

Comment: Note that because you're storing numbers as strings, the max value of AmendmentNo will be the lexographical maximum, rather than the numerical one. E.g.: the max of {'1','2','9','542'} will be '9'.

Comment: no  amendmend no max will be till 10 or more over till 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `GROUP BY` clause. This will give you all `LCNo` with its highest `AmendmentNo`.

```
SELECT LCNo, MAX(AmendmentNo) AmendmentNo
FROM   LCTable
GROUP  BY LCNo
```

but if you want tfor a specific `LCNo`, you can simply use below. Remember that using the query below gets only one `LCNo`.

```
SELECT LCNo, MAX(AmendmentNo) AmendmentNo
FROM   LCTable
WHERE  LCNo = '12147001'
```

Answer (score 3):

For this, use `limit` or `top` or something similar:

```
select *
from LCTable
where  LCNo= '12147001'
order by AmendmentNo desc
limit 1
```

In SQL Server, this would use `top`:

```
select top 1 *
from LCTable
where  LCNo= '12147001'
order by AmendmentNo desc
```

Comment: i tried this "desc limit 1" , but when use it in the admin panel it worked but when i use it in the php code it dosent